# How to print out only a certain amount of elements in a arraylist in java

Tags: java

I have tried several different ways and none have actually worked.

I tried this while loop here:

```
int i = 0;
        while (i  < 14){
          if (i < 14){
            break;
          }
          else {
            for (String str : arraylist)
              {           
             i++;   
               System.out.print(arraylist.get(i));  
            }
```

and i've also tried this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    System.out.print(arraylist.get(i))

}
```

Is there a certain way to print out only a select amount of indexes in a array list? I've been struggling with this for a while. thanks guys.

Comment: The `for` loop should work flawlessly. What does the console show, and what do you expect? Note that the while loop doesn't work because this is wrong `if (i < 14){` it will stop immediately if i is less than 14, you could change it to `if (i >= 14){`

Comment: another option is to define a constant for the desired number of elements similar to:

`int NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS = 5;`

`for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS ; i++)`

Comment: So what is your requirement?? You posted code that doesn't work. That doesn't tell us what your requirement is. Are you trying to display the first "X" items? The last "X" items? The midle "X" items? There is no reason a for loop should not work. You haven't even told us what output you get. Post a proper [mre] That is create an ArrayList using a loop with 100 elements where the value of the item is the value of the index in your loop. Then try to display some of the items. Maybe the problem is how you actually create the ArrayList?

Comment: Your for loop body is missing a semi colon `;` after `System.out.print(arraylist.get(i))`. Add it back and it would work.

Comment: *Your for loop body is missing a semi colon ;* - you get a compile error if you forget the ";". I sure hope the OP would actually state in the question that they can't solve a compile error. That is why an [mre] should be included with every question. We should not be spending time guessing what the actual code is.

Answer (score 2):

Just use for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
  System.out.println(arrList.get(i));
}
```

May be you forgot a semi-column in your for?
Or maybe you got some kind of exception?
if you want to use while you need this code:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 14){
  System.out.println(arrList.get(i));
  i++;
}
```

The problem with your while loop was that you put a for inside a while, and your program firstly goes for a first iteration of while, and then go over a whole arrList, and then does it more and more.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Integer> integers = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
    //print out 5 elements
    integers.stream().limit(5).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 